# Entity Framework Core Interbase -quotation marks issue

Tags: entity-framework-core, interbase

I am facing an issue with Interbase connectivity using Entity Framework Core, following the guidelines provided in this documentation:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Entity_Framework.
The problem arises in the following code snippet:

```
using (var db = new myContext())
{   
    var iqryble = db.Userlists.Select(d => d.USRID);
    var result = iqryble.ToList();
}
```

The generated SQL code includes double quotes around table and column names, which is not valid in the Interbase database. The error received is:

```
Error at line 1
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, char 11
.
SQL - SELECT "u"."USRID"
FROM "USERLIST" AS "u"
```

This issue is due to the double quotes. How can I fix this problem?"

Comment: Please go ahead and include the versions of the Nuget packages you are using, the DbContext and Entities definitions, the Startup section where you register your DbContext with the correct provider...

Comment: [Double quotes are valid](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Naming_Objects). Whatever the problem is, it's not the quotes. Those were generated by the Interbase EF provider, not EF. You can check what the actual query looks like by usin [ToQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-8.0), eg `var sql=iqryble.ToQueryString();`. Can you execute that query directly?

Comment: On the other hand, the Interbase provider isn't exactly popular, with just 2K downloads in the last 2 years. Even so, I'd expect [their official demo code](https://github.com/Embarcadero/IB.NETDataProvider/tree/main/NETProvider/Demos) to work ....... Even though that code contains *Firebird* license text

Comment: thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos , SELECT "u"."USRID"
FROM "USERLIST" AS "u" this is the code generated from EFcore.

Comment: Did you try to run that directly? According to the docs it should work. [The provider code itself](https://github.com/Embarcadero/IB.NETDataProvider/blob/main/NETProvider/Provider/src/InterBaseSql.EntityFrameworkCore.InterBase/Storage/Internal/IBSqlGenerationHelper.cs#L93) adds quotes if the database dialect is 3. What database version are you using and what's the actual connection string?

Comment: I am using InterBase version 14.1.0.231, and when running the provided code (SELECT "u"."USRID" FROM "USERLIST" AS "u" )in the IB console ,its showing the above error.
The connection string 
   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
       if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
       {
         optionsBuilder.UseInterBase("data source=localhost:C:\\FILES\\TESTDB.IB;user id=sysdba;password=masterkey;Dialect=3");
       }
   }